# UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction and VoiceOver: issue or bug in iOS?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

This is a quite strange behavior that 'persecutes' me since iOS 7.0 :) I hope someone of you can help me this time! As you probably know when you are using VoiceOver your gestures are totally different from the 'normal way'. When you need to bypass VoiceOver for a specific view you can set its accessibility traits as `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction`. When the view has this parameter set the user can interact with it as usual (like VoiceOver is not active in that particular view).

Quite often happens that this ability is randomly lost so VoiceOver acts in its normal way.

Did anyone of you encounter this problem in its experience? Did he solve it? Fortunately turning off and on VO seems to temporarily solve this issue (until next time it happens again)

Any idea? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this with other things as well.  For example, notifications can be spotty, particular Screen Changed or Content Changed notifications.  I believe this happens as a result of turning VoiceOver on and off.  For example, if you were to turn VoiceOver on, leave it running, and open your application as a user would, you would never experience these issues.

However, if you use the VoiceOver shortcut.  Or interrupt the application, re-install, and restart while using Xcode, you can disrupt the VoiceOver's connection to the application.  It doesn't bond correctly.  So, simple things like navigation work fine.  But advanced features like notifications (and perhaps some of the more complicated traits) don't work.

Essentially, I would classify this as a bug, but a bug that only shows itself when you use VoiceOver in a way that only a developer would use it.

Comment: Thank you very mush for the reply. Really one other trigger for this bug seems to be activating Zoom while VO is running (and a view with direct interact trait on). This particular situation is quite frequent in very low-sighted user that prefer to have double check (VO and Zoom). This kind of bug is quite difficult tu submit to Apple or to request a TSI for...

Comment: You are correct.  It seems to be somewhat non-deterministic (from an application developers point of view anyway) and most of the interactions involved are private APIs. [

Comment: in this particular case I have a ViewController that adds, as a subview, a view with "things" (for which we need the direct interaction), but... take a look at this: 1) create the view (and its objects), 2) trigger a Screen Changed UIAccessibilityNotification using, as its parameter (the focus) the view for which we need the direct interaction. I'm doing some tests that seem to report that forcing the screen-changed notification   mitigates this issue... Mmh... strange things :)